# filebeat custom processor to mutate the logevents

Tags: filebeat

I was going through filebeat documentation where it has promising feature to process the input logevents- https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuration-processors.html with which I should be able to mutate my logevetns.

The supported processors are:

- add_cloud_metadata
- decode_json_fields
- drop_event drop_fields
- include_fields

Unfortunately, it does not mention how to add custom Processor so that I
can mutate the logevents the way I want. Say I want to process the logs in format,

```
timestamp a:1,b:2,c:100
```

to

```
{ "timestamp" : timestamp, "message" : { "a": 1, "b" : 2, "c": 100}}
```

Logstash could be one solution, but its simply an overhead to send from filebeat to logstash and then to elasticsearch.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: Hey @DylanNicholson Its been a while. Not sure if anything has changed on filebeat but I'm not aware of the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it via [script processor](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/processor-script.html), where you need to provide a custom script (javascript) code to form your new (processed) field.

For example, this is a sample script processor to create a new field based on what you wrote:

```yaml
processors:
  - script:
      when:
        has_fields:
          - "timestamp"
      lang: javascript
      source: |-
        function process(event) {
          var timestamp = event.Get("timestamp");
          var messageObj = {};
          for (var kv of timstamp.split(",")) {
            var kvSplit = kv.split(":");
            messageObj[kvSplit[0]] = kvSplit[1];
          }
          var jsonObj = {timestamp: timestamp, message: messageObj}
          // avoiding collision with existing "message" field, you can use that as well, 
          // and maybe you can rename this field to "message" later after this processor
          event.Put("new_message", JSON.stringify(jsonObj)); // stringifying it, you can try without it.
          return event;
        }
```